# Setting border right and left closer together

Tags: html, css

I have border left and right and I would want them to be closer together so there would be a white space on the right and left. I tried with padding and with negative margins with no success.

```css
.verticalLine {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  border-left: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="verticalLine">
</div>
```

[image]

I would want those 2 red lines to be closer together so there would be some white space on the right and left of them. (I don't want to change the width of this div)

EDIT: code updated

```
<div style="display: table-row;">
<p>Lfdskopfdksoppokfsdpokfs</p>
<div class="verticalLine">
</div>
</div>

p{
  word-break: break-all;
  display: table-cell;
    width: 45%;
}
.verticalLine:before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.verticalLine {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Add a `pseudo-element` and give it 80% width and apply the border on it. Then there will be 10% gap on either side of the parent

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the pseudo-element `:before` to create the vertical lines. Just make it smaller than it's parent, e.g. `60%` and give it the corresponding margin for the gap to the side, in this case e.g. `margin-left: 20%;`. At last use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the borders into the width and center the element properly.

I added a black border to make it easier to see:

```css
.line {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  width: 10%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.line:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-left: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
  border-right: 0.13em solid #ff0000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working because I want the height to be 100% (depends on what in other cells)

Comment: I just solved the problem you posted. Please give your whole table than, if you have problems with it

Comment: I have added the code with your solution that does not work in edit to this question

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 gradients instead of borders and style the background of your elements:

```
table{
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, 
    #fff 0%, 
    #fff 20%, #c00 20%, #c00 calc(20% + 2px), #fff calc(20% + 2px),
    #fff 80%, #c00 80%, #c00 calc(80% + 2px), #fff calc(80% + 2px), 
    #fff 100%);
  width: 50%; 
  height: 200px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/nudebexuhu/edit?css,output)

Comment: Nice solution, but unfortunately the border widths are variable, as they have a 1% width...